# Where can I find resources for self-learning of audio-video production concepts

Tags: video, audio

My father has an audio-video production studio that I wanted to inherit. However, I majored in computer science and have no clue whatsoever about how audio and video production works. The problem here is that I already have the equipment, but I do not know how to use it to produce the expected results. Unfortunately, my father doesn't have deep knowledge of the equipment either. He did his jobs by a conventional wisdom (usually trial and error) and did not take any complicated jobs that required professional knowledge.

My purpose is to extend my father's studio with my computer skills.  However, I am still a total beginner in this audio-video production. Can anyone suggest me where should I start?

What I want to know is the pipeline behind the production, and all the terms and concepts.

For example, I want to know the purpose behind different features in a camera, and the meaning behind all the terms that I've seen on the labels or in an editor software (midi, damping, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

To get familiar with the basic concepts, I would recommend Wikipedia and Google. Just look at the [entry for MIDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI). It's huge. Another example is the [microphone entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone). It is even more huge!

So, investigate the equipment, then Google it and search on Wikipedia. You'll be amazed how much information you'll find.